# Search across multiple columns with a regular expression and extract the match

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have the following data structure and I want to check the presence of a specific string ('^881') across the columns var1 to var4. And to write the result of the match in a new column (RESULT), or an empty result, if the string is not found.

| var1 | var2 | var3 | var4 | EXPECTED RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8810 | 1234 |  |  | 8810 |
| 1234 | 2345 | 3456 |  |  |
| 1234 | 8812 | 2345 | 3456 | 8812 |

I have a solution that gives me the presence of the regex-string in a 0/1-format: (Maybe there is a more concise option?!)

```
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  tibble(
     var1 = c('8810', '1234', '1234'),
     var2 = c('1234', '2345', '8812'),
     var3 = c('', '3456', '2345'),
     var4 = c('', '', '3456')
  )

# create a new column, that indicates whether the string is present in the row (1) or not (0)
df %>% 
  mutate(FOUND = if_else( 
    across( starts_with('var'), 
            ~ str_detect(.x, '^881') 
    ) %>% 
    rowSums(., na.rm=T) > 0, 1, 0))
```

But I need the result of the match, that is the whole string.
After some puzzling, I have found the following solution, but it has a decisive drawback. It is quite slow with large datasets (10m+ cases) and about 100 variables to search. Furthermore, it seems a bit cumbersome to me.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with('var'),
                ~ str_match(.x, '(^881.+)')[,1]  # gives a tibble
  ) %>%   
  mutate(across(everything(),    
                stringi::stri_na2empty)   # replace the NAs with empty strings
  ) %>%  
  unite('RESULT', sep = "")) # make a single column
```

My question: Is there a more concise way to perform this data manipulation (preferably with `dplyr`)?

Comment: Thanks to tmfmnk, ThomasIsCoding, and akrun for their efforts and replies. I tested the solutions with a microbenchmark and all need approx. the same time (surprising to me). If one want to have a look at it you'll find it (on GitHub)[https://github.com/Statistican/68693557/blob/main/test_solutions.R]. Additionally they all give sightly different results: tmfmnk finds all matches separated with commas, akruns finds first match and non-matches are NAs,  ThomasIsCoding finds first, mine finds all, but not well separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(result = str_subset(c_across(everything()), "^881")[1]) %>%
    ungroup
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  var1  var2  var3   var4   result
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1 8810  1234  ""     ""     8810  
2 1234  2345  "3456" ""     <NA>  
3 1234  8812  "2345" "3456" 8812
```

Answer (score 1):

One option with the addition of `purrr` could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(result = pmap_chr(across(everything()), ~ toString(c(...)[str_detect(c(...), "^881")])))

  var1  var2  var3   var4   result
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1 8810  1234  ""     ""     "8810"
2 1234  2345  "3456" ""     ""    
3 1234  8812  "2345" "3456" "8812"
```

Some additional performance improvement could be achieved by replacing the regex by exact matching:

```
df %>%
 mutate(result = pmap_chr(across(everything()), ~ toString(c(...)[str_sub(c(...), 1, 3) == "881"])))
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option

```
inds <- grepl("^881", as.matrix(df))
df$EXPECTED_RESULT <- replace(
  rep("", nrow(df)),
  rowSums(`dim<-`(inds, dim(df))) > 0,
  as.matrix(df)[inds]
)
```

gives

```
> df
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  var1  var2  var3   var4   EXPECTED_RESULT
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
1 8810  1234  ""     ""     "8810"
2 1234  2345  "3456" ""     ""
3 1234  8812  "2345" "3456" "8812"
```